# Performance difference between django.db.models.Model.objects.raw() and django.db.models.Model.objects.filter() in django

Tags: python, sql, django

I am really interested in knowing the performance difference between using a query such as:

`query = MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1)`

AND

`query = MyModel.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM my_models WHERE model_id = 1 ")`

Also, could you please elaborate on why is there such a performance difference?

Thanks a lot,
Saket

Comment: Watch : [Django in depth](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_ziKY1ayCo)

Comment: @hcwhsa Can you please sum it up here itself? Do not have access to YouTube.

Comment: you can see what the ORM generates for you by coercing the QuerySet's `query` attribute to a string!   =)  e.g.  `str(MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1).query)`